# Replacing multiple special characters on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with 80+ columns and column names has special characters like colon, Ampersand, Slash, Minus, space and Parenthesis.

Currently, I'm doing multiple replace on df.columns,
my code  as follows:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','').str.replace('-','').str.replace('&','').str.replace('/','').str.replace(':','').str.replace('(','').str.replace(')','')
```

Is there any betters ways to replace all special characters at once on dataframe column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'[ \-&/:()]', '', regex=True)
```

Some characters need to be escaped in regexes, so to be safe you can get `re` to do it for you:

```
import re
regex = '['+re.escape(r' -&/:()')+']'
# '[\\ \\-\\&/:\\(\\)]'
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(regex, '', regex=True)
```

Comment: yeah this will do the trick for him.

Comment: Thanks below one works better
    import re
    regex = '['+re.escape(r' -&/:()')+']'
    # '[\\ \\-\\&/:\\(\\)]'
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(regex, '', regex=True)

Comment: The second one escapes the characters for you. In my case I forgot the `-` ;)